# Intranet - wordpress - in sharepoint?

Tags: intranet

I currently run our intranet on a completly other domain then our companydomain. I've build this around a wordpress-theme we once purchased - is it somehow possible to configure this into Sharepoint?

-or is my best option to make a tile that links to the site...?

Comment: "Make a Tile that links to the site" ??

Comment: If you are thinking about migration, there is a migrate question already: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/importing-wordpress-to-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress and SharePoint are two completely different platforms. You can't reuse the same theme or stylesheet.  SharePoint has different element IDs, classes and overall DOM structure.

However, there are tools that will help you brand your SharePoint site. You can create a new Theme using SharePoint Colour Palette Tool and Apply it manually through the Browser (Site Settings => Change the Look)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182